# Compare multiple elements

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

So I want to compare four different elements, from four different lists. Something like the example bellow, the problem is that equal should only recieve 2 arguments, is there any function to compare more than 2 elements?

```
(equal (nth 0 '(1 2 3)) (nth 0 '(1 2 3)) (nth 0 '(1 2 3)) (nth 0 '(1 2 3)))
```

Comment: If you're just comparing numbers, you can use `=` which accepts any number of arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any function to compare more than 2 elements?

Many of the comparison functions in Common Lisp accept more than two arguments.  For instance, all of [**=, /=, <, >, <=, >=**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm) accept any number of arguments, which means that you can do

```
(= (nth 0 '(1 2 3))
   (nth 0 '(1 2 3))
   (nth 0 '(1 2 3))
   (nth 0 '(1 2 3)))
```

If you need the specific behavior of **equal** (and not **=**), then you'll want the approach that [coredump proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27319933/1281433).  Since equality is transitive, you can check that every element is **equal** to the first element (or that the list is empty):

```
(defun equal* (&rest arguments)
  (or (endp arguments)
      (let ((x (first arguments)))
        (every (lambda (y)
                 (equal x y))
               (rest arguments)))))
```

```
(equal* 1 1 1 1)
;=> T
```

Actually, since you can call **first** and **rest** with the empty list, you could even get rid of the first case, since **every** will return true when passed the empty list:

```
(defun equal* (&rest arguments &aux (x (first arguments)))
  (every (lambda (y)
           (equal x y))
         (rest arguments)))
```

After that, since this might be a common pattern, you could define a macro to define these for you:

```
(defmacro def-n-ary-equality (name predicate &rest args)
  (let ((arguments (gensym (string '#:arguments-)))
        (x (gensym (string '#:x-)))
        (y (gensym (string '#:y-))))
    `(defun ,name (&rest ,arguments &aux (,x (first ,arguments)))
       (every (lambda (y)
                (,predicate ,x ,y ,@args))
              (rest ,arguments)))))
```

```
(def-n-ary-equality equal* equal)
; ==
(DEFUN EQUAL* (&REST #:ARGUMENTS-1005 &AUX (#:X-1006 (FIRST #:ARGUMENTS-1005)))
  (EVERY (LAMBDA (Y)
           (EQUAL #:X-1006 #:Y-1007))
         (REST #:ARGUMENTS-1005)))
```

Comment: Or `(defun equal* (&rest arguments) (every #'equal arguments (rest arguments)))`.

Comment: @Svante Oh, that's nice too, and exploits the transitivity of the equality predicate in a different way.  Nice!

Answer (score 4):

For example you can compare every element with the first one, something like that:

```
(defun meql (func &rest args)
  (every (lambda (arg)
           (funcall func arg (first args)))
         (rest args)))

CL-USER> (meql #'eq 'a 'a 'a) 
T
CL-USER> (meql #'eq 'a 'b 'a)
NIL
CL-USER> (meql #'equal "foo" "FOO" "foo")
NIL
CL-USER> (meql #'equalp "foo" "FOO" "foo")
T
```

Comment: That's not a bad option in the general case, and it's a an easy way to implement the n-ary comparison/equality predicates.  However, in OP case, where it's numbers that are being compared, the `=` operator would probably work, and is already n-ary.